# Android Display Metrics in Landscape Mode

Tags: android

When an Android device is tilted and goes from portrait to landscape mode, do the values returned in the DisplayMetrics object (i.e., from getDisplayMetrics()) reflect that in that widthPixels now has the larger dimension and heightPixels the smaller?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it does. Why didn't you test by your self?